# CSS - Centered div fill remaining horizontal space

Tags: html, css

Please, I am learning CSS by my self and have 2 questions:

I have 3 DIV inside a "top" DIV, and I need the second (in the center) to fill all the remaining space.

Where is what I got: https://fiddle.jshell.net/3j838det/

[image]

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="first">1</div>
    <div class="second">2</div>
    <div class="third">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
.main {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.main .top {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
}
.main .top .first {
  width: 140px;
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FFCC66;
}
.main .top .second {
  width:auto;
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FF9966;
}
.main .top .third {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FF6666;
}
.main .bottom{
  height:60px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

My questions are:

1. How can I make second DIV to fill all the remaining space?
2. Why there is a space between first and second DIV, and between second and third DIV, if I did not define any margin?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make second DIV to fill all the remaining space?

You can calculate the width of the `.second` class by calculating the remaining width available with `calc`. Like so:

```
width: calc(100% - 264px);
```

The 264 above was calculated from the total `width` from `first` and `third` divs (`140px` + `100px` = `240px`) plus the total padding for all elements (`24px`), which is = `264px`.

---

> Why there is a space between first and second DIV, and between second and third DIV, if I did not define any margin?

You're having gaps because of how `inline-block` works. It's like the spaces between between words. There are a few ways to solve this, but `float: left` should do here. Like so:

```
float: left;
```

Also add `width: 100%` to your `top` element and set it to `display: inline-block`.

Try this [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4yknsboq/)

```css
.main {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.main .top {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.main .top > div {
  padding: 4px;
  float: left;
}
.main .top .first {
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #FFCC66;
}
.main .top .second {
  width: calc(100% - 264px); 
  background-color: #FF9966;
}
.main .top .third {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #FF6666;
}
.main .bottom{
  clear: both;
  height:60px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="first">1</div>
    <div class="second">2</div>
    <div class="third">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, from where did you the the value "264px", in the calc (second DIV) ?

Comment: Ah, sorry I should have explained that part. It is 100px + 140px from your `first` and `third` div + `padding-left` and `padding-right` for each div (8px + 8px + 8px).

Comment: Also, the above solution is compatible with **all** major browsers, including IE8 and above. `Flexbox` is **not** supported in IE8 or IE9 and is only partial support in IE10 and IE11. Some Android devices also have limitations. Check [this link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for Flexbox compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How can I make second DIV to fill all the remaining space?

A job for [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)! :D
Add the following CSS:

```
.main .top {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
.main .top .second {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

> 2. Why there is a space between first and second DIV, and between second and third DIV, if I did not define any margin?

Because there are spaces between the divs in the markup (line break + indentation), and because you display the divs as `inline-block`s.
See also [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239).
Flexbox eliminates this problem though, so you can remove `display: inline-block` at once.

**[ [Updated fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/3j838det/2/) ]**

Comment: When recommending `flexbox`, it's a good idea to mention that it painfully doesn't work on IE until version 10. Which means all previous versions are UN-supported.

Comment: @magreenberg Even IE10 and IE11 has bugs and limitations. I'd say no IE has full support, and even some Android devices have some limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Use the table-cell layout.

```
.main {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.main .top {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.main .top .first {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #FFCC66;
}
.main .top .second {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #FF9966;
}
.main .top .third {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #FF6666;
} 
.main .bottom {
  height:60px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

Comment: It is a very good and simple solution! Do you know if it is valid for IE 9 ?

Comment: Flexbox is not supported in IE9. I've altered my answer for IE9 support.

Answer (score 0):

There are two standard ways to achieve this.

1. `display: table;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.top {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  padding: 4px;
}
.first {
  background-color: #FFCC66;
}
.second {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF9966;
}
.third {
  background-color: #FF6666;
}
.bottom {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="cell first">1</div>
    <div class="cell second">2</div>
    <div class="cell third">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

1. `overflow: hidden;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.top {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
}

.top:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.top .first {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #FFCC66;
}

.top .second {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #FF9966;
}

.top .third {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #FF6666;
}

.main .bottom {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="first">1</div>
    <div class="third">3</div>
    <div class="second">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Inline-block elements alway take some space (depend on it's font size) to it's right side. So better way to use `flex`. But you can use this css below to solve them right now.

```
.main .top>div{
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The spacing between inline-block elements depends on the containers `font-size`.